# Ionic 4 data not automatically update after inserted to backend

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to make an ionic 4 app with basic CRUD in the backend using PHP. So far so good. I've successfully inserted new data through backend into MariaDB/MySQL database. My problem is that the ionic page component doesn't automatically update after data was being inserted into database. I don't know why. I've tried to search for solution on the internet but nothing seem to work. I've read 'changeDetectorRef' and already implement it inside my insert method but it also doesn't work. This things really confuse me. I have to clear cache reload with `ctrl+shift+R` on Chrome in order to see the data changes everytime i do the insert. It the same with devapp. It seems like the browser cache issues so i build the app and see if it also the same and the result was still the same even after i build the app. I cannot see the data changes after insert. Why the page component doesn't automatically updated after inserted into database. Please help anyone.

#### add-data-page.ts

```
//add-data-page.ts

async presentAlert(title,message) {
    const alert = await this.ac.create({
      header: title,
      message: message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    alert.onDidDismiss().then(()=>{
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });

    await alert.present();

  }

 saveData(){
    this.presentLoading("Loading").then(()=>{
      this.dk.insertData(this.mydata).subscribe((result:any)=>{
        this.lc.dismiss();
        this.changeRef.detectChanges();
        this.presentAlert("Succes","New data added");
        console.log(result);
       },_error=>{
         this.lc.dismiss();
       });

    });
```

#### data.service.ts

```
// get data from database
  getDataRest():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl).pipe(
      map(result=>{
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      })
    );
  }

  getDetail(id:any){
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl+'?paramId='+id);
  }

  insertData(data:IDataku):Observable<any>{
      return this.http.post(this.configUrl+'?ins=true',data);
  }
```

#### HomePage to display data

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit{
  result: Observable<IDataku[]>;
    
  constructor(private dk: DatakuService){}

  ngOnInit(){
      this.result = this.dk.getDataRest();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: can you upload your Homepage html file

Comment: here's my homepage html file `<ion-list>
      <ion-item no-margin [routerLink]="['/home',item.id]" *ngFor="let item of (result | async)">
        <ion-label text-capitalize>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>`

Comment: I think after you dismiss the add-data-page you should read data again.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you tell me how exactly do i read the data again in ionic 4?

Comment: Here's what i do after data was inserted : `async presentAlert(title,message) {
    const alert = await this.ac.create({
      header: title,
      message: message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    alert.onDidDismiss().then(()=>{
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });

    await alert.present();

  }`

Comment: I navigate to my homepage if that's what you mean. But that's not working either.

Comment: did you call  presentAlert from home page?

Comment: No, it's from add-data-page

Comment: maybe if you add this.result=null; before this.result=this.dk.getDataRest(); it work

Comment: it's still not working unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit{
  result;
  constructor(private dk: DatakuService){}
  ngOnInit(){
      this.dk.getDataRest().subscribe(data => {

       this.result= data;
      });
    }
}
```